# Creating a Node.js dashboard based on a MySQL DB without a poller

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, node.js

I've read a few StackOverflow posts related to this subject but I can't find anything specifically helps me in my scenario.

We have multiple monitoring instances within our network, monitoring different environments (Nagios, Icinga, more...). Currently I have a poller script written in PHP which runs every minute via cron, it asks the instance to return all of its problems in JSON, the script then interprets this and pushes it in to a MySQL database.

There is then an 'overview' page which simply reads the database and does some formatting. There's a bit of AJAX involved, every X seconds (currently use 30) it checks for changes (PHP script call) and if there are changes it requests them via AJAX and updates the page.

There's a few other little bits too (click a problem, another AJAX request goes off to fetch problem details to display in a modal etc).

I've always been a PHP/MySQL dev, so the above methodology seemed logical to me and was quick/easy to write, and it works 'ok'. However, the problems are: database constantly being polled by many users, mesh of javascript on the front end doing half the logic and PHP on the back doing the other half.

Would this use case benefit from switching to NodeJS? I've done a bit of Node.JS before but nothing like this. Can I subscribe to MySQL updates? Or trigger them when a 'data fetcher' pushes data in to the database? I've always been a bit confused as I use PHP to create data and javascript to 'draw' the page, is there still a split of NodeJS doing logic and front end javascript creating all the elements, or does NodeJS do all of this now? Sorry for the lack of knowledge in this area...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely an area where Node could offer improvements.

The short version: with websockets in the front-end and regular sockets or an API on the back-end you can eliminate the polling for new data across the board.

The long version:

- Front-end:

You can remove all need for polling scripts by implementing websockets. That way, as soon as new data arrives on the server, you can broadcast it to all connected clients. I would advise [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) or the [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) websocket wrapper. Both are very easy to implement and incredibly powerful for what you want to achieve.

All data processing logic should happen on the server. The data is then sent to the client and should be rendered on the existing page, and that is basically the only logic the client should contain. There are some frameworks that do all of this for you (e.g. [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/)) but I don't have experience with any of those frameworks, since they require you to write your entire app according to their rules, which I personally don't like (but I know a lot of developers do).

If you want to render the data in the client without a huge framework, I highly recommend the lightweight but incredibly useful [Transparency](http://leonidas.github.io/transparency/) rendering library. Using this, you can format a Javascript object on the server using Node, JSONify it, send it to the client, and then all the client would have to do is de-JSONify it and call Transparency's `.render`.

- Back-end:

This one depends on how much control you have over the behaviour of the instances you need to check. I assume you have some control, since you can get all their data in a nice JSON format. So, there are multiple options.

1. You can keep polling every so often. This is the easiest solution since it requires no change to the external services. The Javascript [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function is very useful here. Depending on how you connect with the instances, you might be able to use a module like [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to do the actual request, so that takes out a bunch more of the heavy lifting.

   The benefit of implementing the polling in your Node app as well, is that you will receive the data in your Node app and that way you can immediately broadcast it to the clients, even before inserting it into a database. This will greatly reduce the number of queries on your database.
2. An alternative to polling would be to set up a simple [Express](http://expressjs.com/)-based API where the applications can post their 'problems', as you call them. This way your application will get notified the moment a problem occurs, and combined with the websockets connection to the client this would result in practically real-time updates.

   To be more redundant, you would have a polling timer alongside the API, so that you can check the instances in case there's something wrong that causes them to not send over any more data.

   An alternative to the more high-level API would be to just use direct socket communication, which is basically the same approach only using a different set of functions.
3. Lastly, you could also keep the PHP-based polling script. This would be the most efficient solution since you wouldn't go and replace everything. Then from the Node app that's connected to the clients with websockets, you could set an interval to query the database every so often and broadcast the updates. This will still greatly reduce the number of queries, since no matter how many clients are connected there will only be one query, the response of which then gets sent to all connected clients.

I hope my post has give you some ideas of how you could implement your application using Node. Keep in mind though that I am just one developer, this is how I would approach building your application in Node. There will definitely be others who have different opinions.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful and I'm going to do some reading up on some of the technologies you've linked.